# Email notifications on new K2 comment (Joomla 3)

Tags: k2

I need either of these:

- a free plugin that allow me to notify a set of mails on a new k2 comment
- which functions in which files and order of the K2 core are called when I publish a new comment.

Comment: Have you tried searching for an extensions that does this?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution, that may be useful to other.

- a plugin can help: "BNR Comment Notify for K2" but is not free
- Another way is to hack the K2 files, specifically you are interested in "yoursite/components/com_k2/models/item.php" then you should go to comment() function and then modify it using Joomla's object, for the mail, more details here: [Joomla docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions)

Answer (score 0):

I am pleased to present you a new plugin K2. 
Plugin is able to notify you of new comments via email. 
The plugin is absolutely free.
Test, please.
[Interview with the developer and download](http://masterpro.ws/forum/k2/4850-plagin-dlya-k2-dlya-uvedomleniya-o-novykh-materialakh).